# How to add a shape to a geom_smooth?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was wondering if it is possible to add a shape to a geom_smooth line.
If so, how do I accomplish this?

I've looked at some examples though those all talk about geom_line and geom_point combinations.

The reason I would like this is so I can make the distinction between lines in a facet more apparent.

Thanks in advance.

Example:
[image]

Comment: Can you include a reproducible example and an expected output (hand drawing is fine)?

Comment: Maybe you mean `linetype`? `linetype = "dashed"` is a way other than color to distinguish lines. It will work just fine with `geom_smooth`.

Comment: @Gregor No I mean shapes. Like what you can do when you combine geom_line with geom_point and add a shape to the points. So that it looks as if the line has a symbol every now and then. That way you can identify the line by point-shape and color.

Comment: @Tung I don't have a reproducible example. I did add an example of what I have (geom_line() + geom_point(aes(shape = box))) and what I'd like (geom_smooth(aes(shape=box))) as you requested.

Comment: There's no way I know of to automatically add points along a line. What you can do easily  is create a data frame of the point you want to add and add a `geom_point` layer. If you actually want an answer, I would suggest creating a reproducible example. Built-in data would work just fine, perhaps `mtcars`.

Comment: @Gregor This answers my question. Since I couldn't find it in the ggplot2 reference, I was wondering whether someone knew a way to do it maybe through a plugin. Also, there's no way to reproduce the issue because it's not a bug or a problem, I was simply wondering whether it was possible to add shapes to the line automatically as you said. Since, geom_smooth() calculates means and then plots, I was wondering if the means could be given a shape. But like you said, it can't be done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gregor Answered this question in the comments below my OP. 
In short: No it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to do this within `geom_smooth`. What you can do instead is use the `loess` and `predict` functions to create the smoothed series before making hte graph. Using that with `geom_line` and `geom_point` should give you what you want.

For example, here's a graph of a noisy series using `geom_smooth` to smooth it out.

```
x <- 1:25 
y <- x + rnorm(25, 0, 5)

ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x, y), se = F)
```

Plot of x and y using geom smooth:
[image: Plot of x and y using geom smooth]

Here's the same graph, but using `predict` and `loess` to smooth the series before making the graph. The default `loess` settings are the same as what `geom_smooth` uses. Doing this allows me to add the smoothed line and shapes in their own geoms.

```
y.smooth <- predict(loess(y~x))

ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line(aes(x, y.smooth), linetype = 2) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y.smooth), shape = 0)
```

Plot of x and y with shapes, smoothing first:
[image: Plot of x and y with shapes, smoothing first]